# Is there a tool that analyzes the webpage and tells you what SEO you need to work on?

Tags: html, css, search, seo

I'd like to know how to further optimize my site. THanks.

Comment: I dont think this is a SEO forum, its supposed to be a programming forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/

Comment: Check out this video as well, should be helpful: 
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/01/using-webmaster-tools-like-seo.html

Answer (score 1):

A big fan of online tools and utilities, I've recently heard and tried http://webmeup.com, looks both friendly and effective. The tool helps mostly with keyword research and on-page optimization.

Answer (score 0):

I tried http://www.seoscheduler.com/index.php and it had pretty decent (for free) output.